# Why do i get 502 Bad Gateway after deploying Teleport

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, teleport, teleport-cluster

I am deploying teleport cluster into my kubernetes cluster, i use Route53 to route traffic from my domain to an Application Load Balancer. This is an nginx ingress, which works for all my other applications in the cluster.

but when i try to curl the cluster as it is shown in the [documentation](https://goteleport.com/docs/deploy-a-cluster/helm-deployments/kubernetes-cluster/#set-up-dns-records) i get.

> 502 Bad Gateway

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Example would be curl `https://teleport.example.com/webapi/ping`

**Helm command**

```
helm install teleport --set acme=true --set acmeEmail=<my email address> --set clusterName=teleport.example.com --set service.type=ClusterIP teleport/teleport-cluster
```

**Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: teleport
  namespace: telport-cluster
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <CertificateARN>
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "443"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: <Ingress Group>
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
  - host: teleport.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: teleport
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  - host: '*.teleport.example.com'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: teleport-cluster
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

**UPDATE**

When i curl the service endpoint like this `curl -k https://10.0.1.96:3080/webapi/ping` I get the expected result back as shown below, but i cannot seem to curl it without the `-k` flag and also cannot curl the service

```
{"auth":{"type":"local","second_factor":"on","preferred_local_mfa":"webauthn","allow_passwordless":true,"allow_headless":true,"local":{"name":""},"webauthn":{"rp_id":"teleport"},"private_key_policy":"none","piv_slot":"","device_trust_disabled":true,"device_trust":{"disabled":true},"has_motd":false,"default_session_ttl":"12h0m0s"},"proxy":{"kube":{"enabled":true,"listen_addr":"0.0.0.0:3080"},"ssh":{"listen_addr":"0.0.0.0:3080","tunnel_listen_addr":"0.0.0.0:3080","web_listen_addr":"0.0.0.0:3080","public_addr":"teleport:443"},"db":{"postgres_listen_addr":"0.0.0.0:3080","mysql_listen_addr":"0.0.0.0:3080"},"tls_routing_enabled":true,"assist_enabled":false},"server_version":"15.0.2","min_client_version":"14.0.0","cluster_name":"teleport","automatic_upgrades":false}
```

If i ssh into a pod and run curl like so  `curl -k https://teleport.teleport.svc.cluster.local:443/webapi/ping`

I get the below result back

```
<a href="https://teleport:443/web/launch/teleport.teleport.svc.cluster.local?path=%2Fwebapi%2Fping">Found</a>.
```

but if i remove the -k flag, i get the below.

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: Did you install teleport in the same namespace as ingress?

Comment: You have a typo - `telport-cluster` - I suppose it should be `teleport-cluster` - you missed second `e`.
Apart from that I would check if the service name is indeed `teleport-cluster` or maybe just `teleport`.

Comment: @tymik it's not a typo issue because thats just the namespace, and yeah all the resources are in the same namespace